# JPA- mixing entity and non-entity classes

Tags: java, jpa

The subject may be misleading. Essentially, I have 3 "entities" with relationships between them. only one of the entities needs to be persistent (between server restarts). I still want DB functionality across the non-persistent entities ... for example queries.

What's the right pattern to handle this?

I thought about an in-memory DB, but as one of my entities does need to be persistent, i don't think this is an option as the non-persistent entities would be in a different persistence unit.

another thought was just keep everything persistent, but wipe the non-persistent tables when the system restarts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two persistence units.  One two a disk database, and one to an in-memory database.

The relationship would need to be transient, or possibly storing the foreign key to A and B.  Or just don't have the relationship between the two, just perform a query to find A or B when required, as a relationship in a persistent entity that is not persisted seems odd.

Comment: i think the idea of using different PUs + an in in-memory DB, and not (directly) defining  a relationship between the objects in the different PUs sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a JPA question per se. It would apply to whatever persistence mechanism you are using.

If I read your question correctly, the two non-persisting entities could just be POJOs and in a JPA application they would not live in any persistence unit.

You don't describe the relationships, so this is a bit of a guess. If the persisted entity is composed of the other two you might have something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public class PersistingEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @Transient
    A a = new A();

    @Transient
    B b = new B();

    ...
}
```

where A and B are the non-persisted entities.

Comment: `a` and `b` should be marked as `@Transient` otherwise they'll get serialized and persisted as a byte array.

Comment: thanks. i understand that marking them transient will leave them out of persistence, but the problem is that i want the a and b fields to participate in relationships and i want to be able to perform queries on them.

Comment: So instances of A and B will persist for the run time of the application? That is, when you start the app, no instances of A or B will exist, but they will accumulate over time?

Comment: my understanding is that @Transient means "ignore this". those objects are subject the GC rules as any other.